# how to activate 16bit timer on AVR programming

Tags: c, timer, avr, avr-gcc, atmega

I have an atmega168a chip. I use `Counter 0` to toggle `PORTC` by using `ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)` and `ISR(TIMERB_COMPA_vect)` interrupt sub-routines. I would like to activate the `16-bit timer` when `if` condition is true. So, I use `TIMSK1 = (1<<OCIE1A)`, but this line calls `ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)` interrupt instantly where I want 16 bit timer to be interrupted only when the counter `reaches` to `OCR1A` value. How can I activate the 16-bit timer on the run-time without causing an instant interrupt?

here is my code:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdint.h>

volatile uint8_t counter;

int main (void){
    DDRC = 0xFF;  //sets PORTC as output
    PORTC = 0xFF; //initial output value
    /*COUNTER0 settings*/
    TIMSK0 = ((1<<OCIE0A) | (1<<OCIE0B));  // Enable Interrupt TimerCounter0 Compare Match A & B
    TCCR0A = (1<<WGM01);  // Mode = CTC
    TCCR0B = (1<<CS01) | (1<<CS00);   // Clock/64, 1/(8000000/64)= 0.000008 seconds per tick
    OCR0A = 200;      //   0.000008 *230 = 1.6 ms
    OCR0B = 100;      //     0.8 ms

    /*16bit timer - counter1 settings*/
    TIMSK1 &= ~(1<<OCIE1A); // Disable Interrupt Counter 1, output compare A (TIMER1_CMPA_vect)
    TCCR1B = ((1<<CS12) | (1<<CS10) | (1<<WGM12));    // Clock/1024, 1/(8000000/1024) = 0.000128 seconds per tick, Mode=CTC
    OCR1A = 40;                       // 0.000128*40 ~= 5.12 milliseconds

    sei(); //interrupts are globally switched on
    counter =0;
    while(1){
        if(counter >= 4){
            TCNT1 = 0; // clear the counter 1
            TIMSK1 = (1<<OCIE1A);// Enables the interrupt for Counter 1,(TIMER1_CMPA_vect)
            TIMSK0 &= ~((1<<OCIE0A) | (1<<OCIE0B)); //disables the Counter 0's interrupts
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){ //1.6ms
    PORTC = 0xFF;
    counter++;
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect){  //0.8 ms
    PORTC = ~PORTC;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){ // 5.2 milisecond interrupt
    PORTC = 0x00;
    TCNT0 = 0; //clear the counter of counter0
//  TIMSK0 = ((1<<OCIE0A) | (1<<OCIE0B)); //Enable the Counter 0 interrupts
//  TIMSK1 &= ~(1<<OCIE1A);// Disable Interrupt Counter 1, output compare A (TIMER1_CMPA_vect)
}
```

here is an oscilloscope output that shows why I don't want the interrupt to be set instantly, because it set the signal 0 instantly.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be that in CTC mode, interrupt is generated when `OCF1A` flag is set (in `TIFR`). Since your timer is always running, just not generating interrupts, it sets `OCF1A` flag, which never gets cleared. On page 142 in the datasheet it says:

> OCF1B is automatically cleared when the Output Compare Match B
>   Interrupt Vector is executed. Alternatively, OCF1B can be cleared by
>   writing a logic one to its bit location.

This means that when you set up timer 1, you also need to clear `OCF1A`:

```
TIFR1 &= ~(1<<OCF1A)
```

However, I think you can do better.  You could just stop the timer when not needed, and start it when you do, instead of twiddling the `TIMSK` and having timer 1 run always. If you set `TCCR1B` to zero, that clears `CS12`, `CS11`, and `CS10`, which, according to the datasheet means "Timer stopped."  Then, when your counter reaches 4 you can turn on timer1 as you have it above:

```
TCCR1B = ((1<<CS12) | (1<<CS10) | (1<<WGM12));
```

If you do this, you shouldn't need to turn timer 1 interrupts on and off: just leave them on, and only turn the counting on when you need it.

Also I am wondering if it is actually necessary to fire off two interrupts to toggle pins on `PORTC`?  Are you not using PWM for that because it doesn't give you the pulse lengths precisely enough?

Comment: thank you very much, now it works fine. it is not a complete code, I am planning to use 16 bit timer to block a signal output for some miliseconds. I was just experimenting with the code above.